# Number of Objects in Autorelease Pool

Tags: objective-c, memory, nsautoreleasepool

Is there any way to query the number of objects that reside in a given NSAutoreleasePool?

This is really important for me, because in my game there are several loops and I need to know how effectively I'm autoreleasing my autoreleased objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.

Presumably you've got some kind of master control loop that runs your game.  Just create an autorelease pool at the beginning of each iteration and destroy it and the end of the iteration.